# How to silently deploy Adobe Reader DC update through SCCM

Tags: sccm

I'm trying to deploy an Adobe Reader DC update through SCCM and am having trouble installing it silently.  I'm attempting to run it through the command line to make sure it works and here is what I am using that works:

```
msiexec /update AcroRdrDCUpd1500820082.msp
```

That works fine for bringing up the update and then running the .msp manually.  However, if I try running the following the update never works:

```
msiexec /update AcroRdrDCUpd1500820082.msp /qn
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  How can I get this to run silently so that I can deploy it in SCCM?

Answer (score 1):

The way that we've installed/updated Adobe Reader is to just use the /q switch, but choose the Installation program visibility option to 'Hidden' in the User Experience section of the application properties.  Set supersedence to the previous version that you want to update from.

For updates, you can create an app deployment with a script deployment type that runs (include quotes) "AcrobatUpd**.msp" /qn (replace ** with the actual numbers from the .msp).  Set the detection method to whatever specific version(s) you currently have installed.

Comment: I actually installed it using the same options, however I have not been able to get the update to work using the command you are using.  It just runs in the background and never seems to complete...

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you need to specify the relative or absolute path of the location of your update msp file. I use `/qn` but I test with `/qb`.

[Blurb](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/bootstrapper.html)

> [MSI Updater] Path    The absolute or relative path to the required MSI
>   updater file starting with starting from http:// or ftp://. When a
>   fully-qualified URL path os specified, the bootstrapper downloads the
>   new Microsoft Installer first.

Try something like `msiexec /update \\domain.local\pathToMyfile\AcroRdrDCUpd1500820082.msp /qn`

Or use a local path.